# submit the form when user selects a date in date picker

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on angularjs application. I have Available Date and Expire Date picker. When user selects the date from Available Date field, i want  to enable the Expire Date field so that user can select date in Expire Date field. When user selects date in Expire Date field, the text given in "showController" controller should be displayed. Please find the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/1/)

Please advice how to submit or call the showController as soon as user selects date in Expire Date field.

js code:

```
var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ["ui.bootstrap"]);

// create angular controller
demoApp.controller("demoController", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
        var today = new Date();
        $scope.AvailableDate = new Date();
        $scope.ExpireDate = new Date();
        $scope.dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
        $scope.availableDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: "2016-03-12",
            maxDate: today,
               dateDisabled: function(data) {
                var date = data.date;
                var mode = data.mode;
               return (mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ));
            }

        };
        $scope.expireDateOptions = {
            formatYear: 'yy',
            startingDay: 1,
            minDate: today,
            maxDate: "2017-06-12",
            dateDisabled: function(data) {
                var date = data.date;
                var mode = data.mode;
               return (mode === 'day' && ( date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6 ));
            }
        };
        $scope.availableDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.expireDatePopup = {
            opened: false
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate = function(availableDate) {
            if (availableDate != null) {
                var availableDate = new Date(availableDate);
                var expiryMinDate = angular.copy(availableDate);
                expiryMinDate.setDate(expiryMinDate.getDate() + 28);

                $scope.ExpireDate = availableDate;
                $scope.expireDateOptions.minDate = availableDate;
                $scope.expireDateOptions.maxDate = expiryMinDate;
            } else {
                delete $scope.ExpireDate;
            }
        };
        $scope.ChangeExpiryMinDate($scope.AvailableDate);
        $scope.OpenAvailableDate = function() {
            $scope.availableDatePopup.opened = !$scope.availableDatePopup.opened;
        };
        $scope.OpenExpireDate = function() {
            $scope.expireDatePopup.opened = !$scope.expireDatePopup.opened;
        };
    }
]);
```

Currently Expire Date displays next few working days from the date selected in Available Date.

--EDITED--

Please find the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/8/).

I have another controller in my javascript code shown above, that controller should be called as soon as user selects date in Expire Date field.In my application i have backend code which is invoked when user selects date in Expired Date field.

```
  <div ng-controller="showController">
        <h3>
        Submit the form and Show this text when user selects a date in Expire Date field..
        </h1>
   </div>
```

Comment: Is the language used by you is php?? If yes,
Then whenever user selects the expiry date the you can call it using the php script.

Comment: what text do you want to display when user selects date in Expire Date field?

Comment: check if this is what you need.... https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/6/

Comment: @talentedandrew - Please see the edited question. I have another controller in my js code which should be invoked when user selects a date in Expire Date field.Please find the updated code https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/8/

Comment: @participantjava you can create an angular service and use it to check if the expiry date is set.You can set the property in the service object to true when you set the expirey date and in the showcontroller you can retrieve that value to check if its set or not.I have updated the fiddle to demonstrate it https://jsfiddle.net/1ahyk735/10/